# Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, gradle

After import project to new Android Studio i have an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Tabview:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

What's wrong?

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Change to

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    }
```

Additionally, some library of yours might be using com.android.support:support-v4:+ (which v21 is for android-L), so fix that with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
compile ('com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abs:+') { // example
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7' // if you're using appcompat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. this actually works. Thanks to Leonardo Cardoso. Mine build.gradle is

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

You might need to sync by doing File>Synchronize

Comment: No problem at all! Please consider voting up! :D

Comment: @LeonardoCardoso. my rep is too low to vote up. Otherwise,I will definitely do it

Comment: When you are able, don't forget then. :D @aknay

Comment: @LeonardoCardoso voted up for you. Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also force to use the old manifest merger

```
useOldManifestMerger true
```